# Difficulties in migration from BlogEngine.Net to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, migration, blogengine.net

I have to move a clients BlogEngine.Net site to WordPress. I have had people ask why would I want to that, I just am doing what has been requested of me. I have managed to get the BlogML file exported out of BlogEngine.Net. I have gone over it and it looks like everything is there. I have also retrieved all images from posts and put them in a zip.

My questions are in general what difficulties have you experienced doing this? What inconsistencies might I expect to happen during this process?

Hosting: We are going to use DreamHost. Would just your basic LAMP hosting with WordPress installed be enough. I know its enough for the site, but with the BlogML import will there be anything that arises that would need more rights to the machine that basic hosting would provide?

BlogML Import: What is the recommended tool to use to import the XML file into the WordPress site? What has been used tried and true? I found [this tool by Aaron Learch](http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/08/23/breaking-up-moving-blog-engines/) and [this tool by Wayne John](http://www.waynejohn.com/updated-blogml-import-class-for-wordpress/) are these the only 2 options?

BlogML Import: What difficulties may arise with the import process?
What i have learned in the inter-webs that may arise.

[I have seen possible memory size errors.](http://www.kjctech.net/2010/01/06/how-to-import-blogml-file-to-wordpress/)

[Permissions issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499077/unable-to-import-blogml-xml-in-my-word-press-blog)

[Edits to the BlogML file. As well as manual edits after import to be found..... That is kinda scary :0](http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2010/06/moving-from-blogengine-net-to-wordpress/)

So anything you may know that i have not listed would be extremely helpful.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you may run into is a problem with internal links. There are plugins that you can get [Broken Link Checker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/broken-link-checker/) & [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) which will help you fix these problems.

Another problem you might have is with any hosted files, images, etc. If you back these up as well from your current server's images/files directories, you may be able to replace them.

HTH